# 20.04.1 offline installation of 'make' to compile network driver

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, package-management, virtualbox

I got a system with the Realtek RTL8125B chip which is supported in Kernel 5.9. To install the driver from the Realtek website, I need to compile it, but 20.04.1 lacks the make package.
I tried apt-get install make --Download-only in a Virtualbox installation of 20.04.1 to get all dependent packages of make, but that downloads only the make package (most likely as the virtual machine is using the host systems working network interface to download updates previously). Manual installation of separate downloaded make_4.2.1-1.2_amd64.deb with dpkg fails on the offline machine with missing dependent packages.
installing an additional compatible network card is not possible as all PCIe slots are in use.
Any ideas?

Comment: how does 20.04 lack the make package ? it's certainly included in the base installation

Comment: Download all dependencies listed in https://pastebin.com/McLAKESz from ubuntu.pkgs.org and install. This will allow you to install the driver.

Comment: The readme for r8125-9.003.05 states it supports linux kernel 2.6x and 2.4x. All other kernels require compilation. This depends on Compiler/binutils for kernel compilation. The above list contains all the package dependencies required for compilation.

Comment: Are you trying to compile the kernel or the driver? If the kernel has the driver, you don't need to compile it. You can install 20.10, I think. In the meantime, maybe you could use tethering to connect to the internet using a mobile device?

Comment: @Zanna I'd advise against 20.10 until it's released - it's not even in Final RC freezes yet

Comment: @trinarycoast: this list of dependenicies was what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis on my system the install script of the network driver fails with the message 'need make' (or something similar) - hence it does not come with the base installation files. Probably on your system it is loaded during installation with a working network interface (which I do not have)

Comment: Since @TrinaryCoast 's answer helped you, I will edit it and undelete it so you can possibly accept it if it works

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem, installing a `dkms` wifi driver. Here's how I did it:

I had a working Ubuntu system, `wombat`, connected to the internet.

I also had `bk`, with Ubuntu installed, but no internet. The driver for its wifi chip was available via `dkms`, which required compiling.

I used a USB key and SneakerNET, along with this process.

On `wombat`, download the `.deb` package for the driver with `apt download`, storing it on the USB key.

AGAIN:

Move the USB key to `bk`, and `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

If/when that fails, save the error log to the USB key.

Move the USB key back to `wombat`, use `apt download` to download the missing packages, saving the `.deb` files to the USB key.

Go back to AGAIN.

Eventually, after 3-5 iterations, you'll have downloaded the original driver, its dependencies and their dependencies and ...

The `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` will succeed, and we're done.

Answer (score -1):

Download all dependencies from [ubuntu.pkgs.org](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/) and install. This will allow you to install the driver.

Here is the list:

```
autoconf_2.69-11.1_all.deb
automake_1.16.1-4ubuntu6_all.deb
autotools-dev_20180224.1_all.deb
binutils_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
binutils-common_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
cpp-9_9.3.0-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb
debianutils_4.9.1_amd64.deb
dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu3_amd64.deb
gcc-10-base_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
gcc_9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
gcc-9_9.3.0-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb
gcc-9-base_9.3.0-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb
lib32asan5_9.3.0-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb
lib32atomic1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
lib32gcc1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
lib32gcc-9-dev_9.3.0-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb
lib32gcc-s1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
lib32gomp1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
lib32itm1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
lib32quadmath0_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
lib32stdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
lib32ubsan1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libacl1_2.2.53-6_amd64.deb
libasan5_9.3.0-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libatomic1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libbinutils_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libbz2-1.0_1.0.8-2_amd64.deb
libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb
libc6-i386_2.31-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb
libc6-x32_2.31-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb
libcrypt1_4.4.10-10ubuntu4_amd64.deb
libctf0_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libctf-nobfd0_2.34-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libdb5.3_5.3.28+dfsg1-0.6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libgcc-9-dev_9.3.0-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libgcc-s1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libgmp10_6.2.0+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
libgomp1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libisl22_0.22.1-1_amd64.deb
libitm1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
liblsan0_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
liblzma5_5.2.4-1_amd64.deb
libmpc3_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb
libmpfr6_4.0.2-1_amd64.deb
libpcre2-8-0_10.34-7_amd64.deb
libperl5.30_5.30.0-9build1_amd64.deb
libquadmath0_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libselinux1_3.0-1build2_amd64.deb
libsigsegv2_2.12-2_amd64.deb
libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libtsan0_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libubsan1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libx32asan5_9.3.0-10ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libx32atomic1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libx32gcc1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libx32gcc-s1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libx32gomp1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libx32itm1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libx32quadmath0_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libx32stdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libx32ubsan1_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libzstd1_1.4.4+dfsg-3_amd64.deb
list
m4_1.4.18-4_amd64.deb
make_4.2.1-1.2_amd64.deb
perl_5.30.0-9build1_amd64.deb
perl-base_5.30.0-9build1_amd64.deb
perl-modules-5.30_5.30.0-9build1_all.deb
tar_1.30+dfsg-7_amd64.deb
zlib1g_1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: The readme for r8125-9.003.05 states it supports linux kernel 2.6x and 2.4x. All other kernels require compilation. This depends on Compiler/binutils for kernel compilation. The above list contains all the package dependencies required for compilation.

Comment: Apparently this is a brand new chip, so I'm kind of confused as to which readme is talking about an ancient kernel and why.